# How to create function in Jenkinsfile?

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I create a function in Jenkinsfile as below

```
def image_exists(repo_name){
sh '''#!/bin/bash 
     echo "${repo_name}"  && echo "TEST" '''
}
```

It print TEST but it print blank line instead of repo_name
What should I do to print repo_name?
I try

```
 echo $repo_name
 echo ${repo_name}
 echo repo_name
```

I call it by

```
IMAGE_EXIST=image_exists("test")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use double-quotes after `sh` command, single quotes do not support interpolation:

```
def image_exists(repo_name){
sh """
    #!/bin/bash
    echo \"${repo_name}\"  && echo \"YYY\"
"""
}
```

Comment: @yasinlachini I sent you invite in Linkedin. By the way, you could omit sha-bang (`#!/bin/bash`) from you Jenkinsfile, as `sh` command do not need it